# Series of Starting and Ending Index for Specific pattern of substring in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, indexing, substring

```
string str = "AAA  AAAAA    AA"
```

I need to figure out starting and Ending index of AAA,AAAAA,AA. In the above example, the index are (1,3),(6,10),(14,16). Is it possible to achieve this 
by using regex

Comment: Wouldn't the last couple be (14,15)? And do you really want to start your index at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: A regex that matches the first and last character would look like [this](http://regex101.com/r/eC9aI5): `(\S)(?:\S*(\S))?`. I don't know if C# can give you the index of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The correct index number will be OK for me. My calculation for index for above example is wrong.

Comment: @HamZa - There could be more set of substring of different length with more spaces between them.

Comment: @vicage `\S` with **S uppercase** matches anything except white space. I've added some comments in a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mD1qP2). Since you didn't specify what `A` may be, this will even match `###`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @[HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza)'s comment: You could do something like this:

```
var r = new Regex(@"(\S)(?:\S*(\S))?");
var input = "AAA  AAAAA    AA";
var clusterPositions = r.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => new{start = m.Index, 
                                           end = m.Index + m.Length});
```

Comment: what if there is one more condition to check if the length of substring should be equal or greater than 4

Comment: @vicage Accept this answer, do some research. If you're stuck, ask a new one.

Comment: Sure HamZa.. Thanks for prompt response.

Comment: @vicage Since I'm in a good mood, I'll give it right away `(\S)\S{2,}(\S)`. [See it working](http://regex101.com/r/rQ7sG2).